# Extra White space in top of html page

Tags: html, css, reactjs, safari, microsoft-edge

Just created a new react app using create-react-app and run it on browser. I got extra white space just above the body content. On inspecting, browser showed that white space is coming from HTML tag. Am in safari Version 15.6.1 (17613.3.9.1.16), Mac OS 12.5.1 (21G83). How to get rid off this white space and make my page to fill the whole screen. [attached screen shots]. It happens in both Edge and Safari browser. Edge version is Version 105.0.1343.27 (Official build) (x86_64)

I already tried settings margin, padding to html, body tags but none helped

[image: In safari]

[image: In edge]

Comment: Please post your code as text.  Otherwise it is a tad hard for anyone to help yoo.

Comment: please post your css code, try to set the margin and padding of all elements to 0px, write in your css file this       * { margin:0;padding:0}           see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

can you set the html to padding 0 and marging 0px

in your CSS file

```
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

- indicate all the elements in the document.